# Access an extended JPanel from a listener in another class

Tags: java, swing

I would like to access an extended JPanel from a listener in another class, in order to re-size that panel when the button is clicked.

I tried to access it using `Buttons.this.setPreferredSize`...., but i got this error

> No enclosing instance of the type Buttons is accessible in scope

My Buttons class looks like this

```
public class Buttons extends JPanel {
    public Buttons() {

    //code

    }
}
```

and the other from where i want to change the size of the Panel

```
public class InterfaceCalc extends JPanel {
    // others codes 
    expandIcon = new ImageIcon("src\\img\\expand.png");
    expand = new JButton("", expandIcon);
    expand.setBorderPainted(false);
    expand.setContentAreaFilled(false);
    expand.setFocusPainted(false);
    expand.setOpaque(false);
    expand.setMargin(new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0));
    expand.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if (!on) {
                Buttons.sqrt.setVisible(true);
                Buttons.log.setVisible(true);
                Buttons.cos.setVisible(true);
                Buttons.sin.setVisible(true);
                // this is where is want to access the panel
                Buttons.this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension());

                on = true;

            } else {
                Buttons.sqrt.setVisible(false);
                Buttons.log.setVisible(false);
                Buttons.cos.setVisible(false);
                Buttons.sin.setVisible(false);

                on = false;

            }

        }

    });
  // others codes 
}
```

How can achieve that ?

Comment: What do you expect `Button.this` to point to?

Comment: I was expecting it to point to the `extended JPanel` , i could  access it from the same class using `button.this` , that's why i tried it in the second class.

Comment: like this `ButtonssetPreferredSize(new Dimension(500,500))` ?

 i did it and it got this  `Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method setPreferredSize(Dimension) from the type JComponent`

Comment: `this` refers to the instance of the enclosing class (relative to the statement where `this` is called). Hard to tell from your question, but I think that you want to create a `Buttons` instance inside `InterfaceCalc` and then perform on that instance the operations in `actionPerformed`.

Comment: thanks guys, I fixed the problem by creating an instance of  `Buttons` outside the listener. before ,the extended panel was added directly like this in `this.add(new Buttons())` in the`InterfaceCalc` panel,  now after i created the instance I added it to the panel and i used it to change the size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed the problem by creating an instance of Buttons outside the listener. before ,the extended panel was added directly like this in this.add(new Buttons()) in theInterfaceCalc panel, now after i created the instance I added it to the panel and i used it to change the size.